# To disturb, disturbing and to bother - the usage

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to understand the way **'to disturb', 'disturbing'** and **'to bother'** could be used when the subject is not a living being. In my cases, they are used in the meaning that 'it spoils something or causes trouble'.

Do these sentences make sense, can be used and sound natural?

1. The noise from road traffic **disturbed** my sleep.
2. My sleep was **disturbed** by the air conditioner.
3. The city buzz **disturbs** my sleep.
4. At 7 am, someone turned on the washing machine next to my room. It was **disturbing**. (with the meaning--> it spoiled my sleep; i couldn't sleep because there was noise.)
5. The smell of cigarette smoke **bothered** me. (with the meaning - I didn't like it; I couldn't stand it)

Comment: Note that *It was disturbing* would usually be understood as *It caused anxiety*. For your example #4, *It was **disruptive*** more accurately conveys the sense you intend. And overall it's becoming increasingly common today to speak of ***disrupted** sleep [patterns]* rather than ***disturbed** sleep [patterns]*.

Comment: "... disturbed **my** sleep" would make the examples better.  You can [edit] this in.

Comment: Thank you! @FumbleFingers, so the sentence 'the noise disrupted my sleep' would sound better than that with 'disturbed'?

Comment: Wow. The first dictionary I looked at gave three meanings, "Interfere with the normal arrangement or functioning." Or "cause anxiety." Or "interrupt sleep, relaxation, or privacy." Nothing says that the subject or object of the verb must be a human agent: "The wind blowing through the windows disturbed the neatly arranged papers on the desk."

Comment: @Jeff I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @ronja There is **nothing** unidiomatic or vulgar about "The noise disturbed my sleep." According to ngram, "disturbed my sleep" is more common than "disrupted my sleep."

Comment: @Jeff Thank you for your effort! I am not a native speaker and sometimes don't have much confidence in what I want to say in English, especially in writing. I usually consult dictionaries when I am uncertain, but there is so much more confidence when a native speaker reassures that it is acceptable. Languages tend to play tricks. What is very common in one language, can be totally unacceptable in another. Thank you once again and apologies if my questions seem too basic sometimes.

Comment: @ronja That is what we are here for. But it does help to consult a dictionary first. And here your instinct was correct that some of the sentences did sound a bit odd. That, however, was not a result of your choice of verb; rather it was the lack of indication about who was being disturbed.

Comment: Note that you left out a word that falls into the same parallel construction: **bothering**.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and time spent on this! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @Jason, thank you for pointing it out! Do you perhaps have a good example when 'bothering' could be used in this context?

Comment: For example: *The noise from road traffic is bothering [my sleep].* While it's a bit uncommon to hear it used that way, it's not actually wrong.

Comment: Thank you Jason! Now, I have one more way I can formulate my idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I can see there has been a lot of discussion of this in comments, but no actual answer, I will attempt to put one together:

I do think that this question is more subtle than can easily be answered by a dictionary.  All of the sentences in question are grammatically correct, and sound fairly natural, but some of them may not have exactly the meaning intended.  Let's look at each of the suggested sentences, for a start:

> The noise from road traffic disturbed my sleep.

This says that the noise caused your sleep to be different (by implication, worse) than normal.  It has been suggested that "disrupted" would be a better word here, but that depends a bit on exactly what you mean to convey.  When your sleep is "disturbed", it generally implies that you continued to sleep, but that sleep was of poor quality (not normal).  However, if your sleep is "disrupted", that implies that your sleep cycle was actually broken (i.e. that you woke up).  As such, the two are not completely interchangeable.

However, while it's not really unnatural (it sounds fine), I think it is somewhat less common to say "my sleep was disturbed".  In general, it's probably more idiomatic to say something like "Because of the noise, I didn't sleep well" instead..

> My sleep was disturbed by the air conditioner.

This is the same thing, just put in the passive voice.  It has pretty much the same implications as the previous sentence, with the same caveats.

> The city buzz disturbs my sleep.

This is the same thing, but put in the present tense instead of the past tense.  It means pretty much the same thing as the previous sentences, but it implies that what you are talking about continues to go on and was not just something that happened in the past. (e.g. "The noise disturbed my sleep (last night)" vs. "The noise disturbs my sleep (every night)")

> At 7 am, someone turned on the washing machine next to my room. It was disturbing.

(with the meaning--> it spoiled my sleep; i couldn't sleep because there was noise.)

So here we get into a difference, mainly because you haven't specified "sleep" anywhere.  Without that, the implication is that it was "disturbing me", rather than "disturbing my sleep", which is not the same thing.  As others have mentioned, saying something is "disturbing" by itself implies that it is unsettling or makes you uneasy in some way ("The pictures of that car accident were disturbing."), which is obviously not what you meant here.

> The smell of cigarette smoke bothered me.

(with the meaning - I didn't like it; I couldn't stand it)

This sentence is perfectly natural, and means exactly what you intended.

This is actually a good example, though, of the difference between "disturb" and "bother".  "bother" implies causing someone annoyance or hardship, whereas "disturb" implies changing (or moving) something (usually in an undesirable or disorderly way).  When applied to people, "disturb" generally means "affecting them emotionally", but that effect is not necessarily annoyance (in fact, as mentioned, it is usually assumed to be uneasiness instead), so the two are not really interchangeable.

"It bothered me" = "it made me annoyed"

"It disturbed me" = "it made me uneasy"

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining the usage! :-)